# Insert with Primary key column in the middle of the table

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.6

I decided to add a primary key to a table after I created the table. This was fine until i wanted to add additional columns to the table.

Now I can't figure out how to insert a row.

```
Insert into MyTable( "Value 1", "Value 2", Primary key, "Value 3", "Value 4" )
```

Is there a placeholder that I can put in the primary key column that will work or is my only option to rebuild the table. I'll have to rebuild it at some point but it's still growing so I'd like to postpone rebuilding it until it stabilizes some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a column list explicitly :

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable (field1, field2,field3,... ) VALUES ('Value1', 'Value2', ...);
```